# How can I remove duplicate rows in MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I've cobbled together the following SQL Query to report on sales from a Magento website. It works as I want, apart from the fact that it's duplicating every row. For example:

```
Name    |   Product     |   Quantity
Fred    |   Prod 1      |   3
Fred    |   Prod 1      |   3
Sarah   |   Prod 2      |   1
Sarah   |   Prod 3      |   1
Sarah   |   Prod 2      |   1
Sarah   |   Prod 3      |   1
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

```
SELECT CONCAT(address.firstname, ' ', address.lastname) AS Name,
       address.email AS Email,
       items.order_id AS Order_ID,
       items.created_at AS Date,
       items.name AS Description,
       items.sku AS SKU,
       items.qty_ordered AS Quantity,
       items.price AS Price,
       items.original_price AS Original_Price,
       items.tax_amount AS Tax_Amount,
       items.base_cost AS Base_Cost,
       shipment.carrier_code AS Carrier,
       shipmentcost.base_shipping_amount AS Shipping_Cost
FROM sales_order AS orders
JOIN sales_order_item AS items ON items.order_id = orders.entity_id
LEFT JOIN sales_order_address AS address ON orders.entity_id = address.parent_id
LEFT JOIN sales_shipment_track AS shipment ON shipment.order_id = orders.entity_id
LEFT JOIN sales_order AS shipmentcost ON shipmentcost.entity_id = orders.entity_id
WHERE items .created_at BETWEEN '2020-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-30 00:00:00'
  AND orders.status = 'complete'
```

Comment: Your show a result set with three columns and a query that returns more than a dozen.  I have no idea what your issue really is.

Answer (score 0):

---add group by

```
Group BY
address.email ,
items.order_id ,
items.created_at ,
items.name ,          
items.sku ,
items.qty_ordered ,
items.price ,
items.original_price ,
items.tax_amount ,
items.base_cost ,
shipment.carrier_code ,
shipmentcost.base_shipping_amount
```